# Secure Silverlight to Web-Service communication without IIS using Public-key cryptography

Tags: silverlight, web-services, security

If I have a Silverlight client connecting to a web service hosted in a windows service, there's no obvious way to secure communications between the two if you're not using IIS. SSL isn't available, and wsHttpBinding isn't supported by Silverlight.

So here's what I'm planning on doing, and just wanted to see if I'd missed any obvious security holes. This will all be on an intranet, SSL-secured hosting on IIS will be used if we ever make it internet-enabled.

1. Create a certificate and put it in the user store for the service account for the web service. Web-service retrieves the certificate keys on startup.
2. Add a clear-text method to the web service to return the public key from the certificate as a string.
3. Call the web-service from the Silverlight client to get the public key.
4. Encrypt all data sent to the web-service from the Silverlight client using the public key. The data returned to the Silverlight client does not need to be encrypted.

Am I missing anything? I can't figure out any other way to do it!

Comment: Why do you think SSL isn't available in a self hosted windows service? Or is it more no-one will setup a CA or pay for a certificate? WCF is certainly capable of hosting HTTPS endpoints in self hosted systems

Answer (score 0):

You can't encrypt large ammounts of data with RSA cryptography, is just too darn slow (100s of ms per RSA modulus length I think). All schemes use RSA to bootstrap a symmetric key and encrypt the data using this key. Use any of the established key exchange protocols. You'd be surprised how easy is to implement SSL 3.0 or TLS 1.0 if you have a copy of Rescorla's book [SSL and TLS: Designing and Building Secure Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615983)

Comment: You are correct, I should have specified that only data in need of protection would be encrypted, such as user credentials.

Comment: How do you plan to ensure that the certificate is not comming from an attacker in-the-middle? Are you going to verify that the certificate is signed by a trusted authority (trusted by the client or trusted by you?) and has appropiate attributes (ie. subject) ?

Comment: I'm not, this will be on an intranet so I think the risk is acceptable. If there is any chance of that I'd host it in IIS instead, I think.